# ActiveRecord not properly quoting query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Cucumber scenario that fails in the following way:

```
  Scenario: I can create a blog post                  # features/blog/create_blog_post.feature:6
    Given I am the super admin                        # features/step_definitions/post_steps.rb:1
      PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
      LINE 1: SELECT  "user".* FROM "user"  ORDER BY user.updated_at desc ...
                                                         ^
      : SELECT  "user".* FROM "user"  ORDER BY user.updated_at desc LIMIT 1 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
      (eval):8:in `instance_eval'
      (eval):8:in `dashboard'
      ./features/support/world_extensions.rb:51:in `sign_in_with'
      ./features/step_definitions/post_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am the super admin$/'
      features/blog/create_blog_post.feature:7:in `Given I am the super admin'
    When I create a blog post                         # features/step_definitions/post_steps.rb:5
    Then that blog post should show up on the website # features/step_definitions/post_steps.rb:14
```

Obviously, the problem here is that `user` is not getting quoted properly (it is in fact called `user`, not `users`). Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your test db is not up to date. Try `rake db:test:prepare` at first.

Comment: I did that. It's not that the `user` table is missing. It's that since `user` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL, you have to put it in quotes if you use it as a table name, and ActiveRecord is not putting it in quotes.

Comment: @JasonSwett, shouldn't the table name be "users" instead of "user" in your case? If the model name is User, then the table name will be users.

Comment: I use psql as well and have users tables often(through Devise). I havn't met such problem before.

Comment: No, I use singular table names.

Comment: SQL shown in my console: `User.find(1)` => `User Load (10.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]`